# Javascript Add text depending on cookie value

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a cookie that saves the value of the selected option from a drop-down menu.

Depeding on the cookie value, a text is entered using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($('page_3').length) {
$('#my_element').after('<div id="greet">XXXXXX</div>');
}
});
```

The text to the be entered will be taken from the following variable depending on the cookie value:

```
var welcome = {
en:"English",
es:"Espanol",
fr:"Francais"
}
```

If the cookie value is 'en' the 'XXXXXX' should be replaced by 'English'. If the cookie value is 'es' the 'XXXXXX' should be replaced by 'Espanol' .... and so on.

I'm using jquery and the jquery.cookie plug-in to set and read the cookie:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

I tried the following code but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#greet').html(welcome[$('$.cookie('cookie_name')]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax is incorrect for use of `$.cookie`

Also you need to cover situations where cookie isn't set either due to first visit or cookies are disabled

Try changing

```
welcome[$('$.cookie('cookie_name')]
```

To

```
welcome[$.cookie('cookie_name')]
```